# Ruby On Rails: Third Normal Form Active Record Assocations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, database-normalization

Pretty simple question... In my system I have multiple "sources" and "destinations", I also have multiple "jobs" which handle input from the source and take it to the destination.

In my database, I've set this up as such with the ultimate aim that the same destination and/or source can be reused in multiple jobs:

Table: destinations

Table: sources
Table: jobs

Table: job_sources

Table: job_destinations

Just dealing with destinations for a minute, in Ruby, my "Job" model has the following line:

```
has_many :job_destinations
```

And in my "job_destinations" model:

```
belongs_to :job
```

Of course - all this does is (correctly) link the job and the job_destination up in Ruby, but not to the actual destination itself... Is it possible to use active record associations to use a "linking table" to link two models together?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. You can't have done any research on the topic or you'd have found this documented in many places. Start here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html and search the page for "many-to-many".

Answer (score -1):

Looks like this is possible using the has_many :through assocation. Just found it in the docs! I'll update my answer with more info if it works out as I expect